# TclDevKit-5.2 prefix file doesn't exist

Tags: tcl, tcldevkit

I am trying to use the trial version of ActiveState's [TclDevKit-5.2](http://www.activestate.com/tcl-dev-kit).

I am getting an error message like this:

```
-prefix "/opt/TclDevKit-5.2/bin/tdkbase" does not exist
```

when trying to wrap a simple tcl file with command like this:

```
/opt/TclDevKit-5.2/bin/tclapp -prefix /opt/TclDevKit-5.2/bin/tdkbase -out app empty.tcl
```

However, file /opt/TclDevKit-5.2/bin/tdkbase exists, and when typing /opt/TclDevKit-5.2/bin/tdkbase, it launches a tclsh session!

I am on 64 bit CentOS, and here is what uname -a returns:

```
Linux hp1 2.6.18-194.11.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 10 19:05:06 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make tclapp to use the prefix file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use path in quotes

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the whole `tclapp` quite problematic to execute. I would recommend you to create a project file and use it as

```
/opt/TclDevKit-5.2/bin/tclapp -config "myproject.tpj"
```

There you have the advantage that you can easily test different combinations and keep it in a single configuration file.